# Connect to Amazon RDS with Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm running a RDS MySQL server and is moving my current environment to this.
I can connect fine with MySQL Workbench, but I'm getting the following, when trying to connect trough my .NET application with Entity Framework:

```
EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
...
MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
...
SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known
```

My connectionstring looks like this:

```
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Database.csdl|res://*/Database.ssdl|res://*/Database.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=name.*.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com,3306;user id=Username;password=Password;persist security info=True;database=DBName&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

As I can connect in MySQL Workbench, I believe the Security Settings on AWS is correct.
Hopefully some of you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, that if you leave the portnumber out of the connectionstring everything works out just fine.
I think it's getting too late.
At least I hope this helps someone :)

Comment: I had the same problem with SQL Server, omitted the port in the connection string, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems can be a trouble with security groups. My [answer at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830418/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-mysql-connector-6-8-3-an/49678955#49678955) can help someone